# Tabs inside of a Dialog causes the Dialog's height:auto to not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

**Solved:** See comments below.

---

I've created a Tabs inside of a Dialog box, but the height of the Dialog does not correspond with the height of the tab.

In this particular case, there is a form inside of the tab. If the user submits the form and there are errors present, the tab's height will increase to display the errors. However, the height of the parent dialog does not automatically resize to match the height of the tab inside.

```
|-tab1-|-tab2-|------|
|                    |
|-(end of dialog)----| (text stops here)
 |                  |
 |                  |
 |                  |
 |-(end of tab)-----| (not visible)
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Hmmm, odd, I have the same setup on a very large system and it doesn't have any issues...Can you duplicate the issue on something like JSFiddle and show us the code?

Comment: What options are you passing to the Dialog/Tabs? I'll try to recreate it and post a link.

Comment: **Dialog options:** `modal: true, overlay: { opacity: 0.5, background: 'white' }, bgiframe: true, autoOpen: false, position: 'center', title: 'some title string', width: 660, height: 530, dialogClass: 'contentAdd', resizable: true, draggable: true, closeOnEscape: false, show: null, close: function(){  $( this ).dialog( 'destroy' ); }` **Tabs options** `selected: 1, show: function( e, ui ){ _tabHandler( e, ui ); }`

Comment: Turns out it was a rogue `position:absolute` set for the class `.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-panel` in the jQuery UI stylesheet that was causing the problem. After I removed that, the problem disappeared.

Comment: Glad you figured it out!

Comment: Ryan, could you post an expanded description of your solution as an answer in case someone else has the same problem in the future?

Comment: Can you answer your own question in a way that would help others? If you do, you can select yours as the correct answer. It may seem strange, but it is the preferred way of dealing with situations like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the following default jQuery UI CSS:

```
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-panel { 
    display: block;
    border-width: 0; 
    padding: 1em 1.4em;
    background: none;
}
```

...had received an extra line of CSS making it impossible for the contents in the tab to resize automatically:

```
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-panel { 
    display: block;
    border-width: 0; 
    padding: 1em 1.4em;
    background: none;
    position: absolute; //This line was causing the problem
}
```